# Graph check if path exist between three nodes

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

The problem is following we have to find path from A to C that goes thru node B or following example graph **A**-G-F-**B**-L-**C**.

Now to implement from A to C is easy using BFS, but I don't know how to make sure that this path passes thru B ?

Comment: Is your graph directed? Do we need to find a **simple path**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By 'path' you probably mean 'simple path' - a path with no repeating vertices.

First, ensure that A, B, and C are connected.

An A-...-B-..-C path exists iff:

- There is no cut-vertex that splits A, B, and C into 3 different components
- A is not a cut-vertex that splits B and C into different components
- C is not a cut-vertex that splits B and A into different components

Comment: @DAle: Thanks. Answer revised.

Comment: @LiorKogan but how would you actually find the path?

Comment: @fafl: That is a different question ;-). The OP only asked for a verification algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

First run a bfs to reach the intermediate node, then run a bfs from that intermediate node to your desired goal node.

Comment: No. These two paths may contain common vertices beside B.

Comment: @LiorKogan Just keep your list of visited nodes then

Comment: @fafl: Still not good. Different vertex ordering in the BFS algorithm may give different results.

Comment: @LiorKogan Please, where in the question have you found the limitation that the paths to and from B can't have other common vertices?

Comment: @Gangnus: Quoting Wikipedia: In graph theory, a path in a graph is a finite or infinite sequence of edges which connect a sequence of vertices **which, by most definitions**, are all distinct from one another.

Comment: @LiorKogan I think, it is up to the questionner to say what he needs. In 99% of cases we all solve some practical tasks. And we do not know what they call "path" in their domain. Maybe, you are right. But I would wait for some correcting edition from the author.